# Loader is processing data even after onLoadFinished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am saving data from server to local database in an AsyncLoader(inside onLoadFinished method i am starting next activity where i want to display saved data), but database is actualy empty, also it happens only when new data is added(i mean it works well with existing database records), how can i fix this?

**Activity**

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList> {
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.laoding_activity);

        context = this;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, bundle, this).forceLoad();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(Utils.MANUAL_START_RECIEVER);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<ArrayList> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        DatabaseWorker loader= null;
        args.putString(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE,Utils.LOAD_All_DATA);
        loader = new DatabaseWorker(this,args);
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<ArrayList> loader, ArrayList data) {
        Log.e("adad",App.session.getActionsGreenDao().loadAll().size()+"");
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<ArrayList> loader) {

    }
}
```

**loadInBackground**

```
 @Override
    public ArrayList loadInBackground() {
        Log.e("loader created","loading");
        switch (command) {
            case Utils.LOAD_All_DATA: {
                saveActivities();
                savePersons();
                savePictureData();
                return new ArrayList();
            }
            case Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA: {
                readActionData();
                return (ArrayList) Action.listAll(Action.class);
            }
            case Utils.READ_PERSONS_DATA: {
                readPersonsData();
                return (ArrayList) Person.listAll(Person.class);
            }
            default:{
                return new ArrayList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of DB do you use? And how do you insert data? As i understood you do it in async thread transaction. After that method onLoadFinished is invoked. But commit operation in db needs some time depends on data size. That is why your db is empty in ui thread. You can check it. For example like this:

```
new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("adad",App.session.getActionsGreenDao().loadAll().size()+"");
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        },1000);
```

Comment: I am using GreenDAO, i am saving data inside asyncLoader, when it is saved Loader starts onLoadFinished and iside it i am starting activity theat actualy view the data(i am reading from database also using AsyncLoader) so your case is almost imposible.